# I want to do calculation inbetween column table and the values should be stored in Final Amount column

Tags: jquery, html

Kindly help me am new to this. I want to do calculation (selected value divisible by 1000) and multiple with Amount and that should be stored in 5th column.
ie Product1 = (100 / 1000) * 100 = 10

Here is my code:

```
<table border="1">
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td width="334">S.No.</td>
        <td width="334">Product Name</td>
        <td width="334">Amount</td>
        <td width="334">Grams/Kg</td>
        <td width="334">Final Amount</td>
    </tr>
    <tr align="center">
        <td>1</td>
        <td>Product1</td>
        <td>100</td>
        <td>
            <select id="grams">
                <option value=""></option>
                <option value="100">100g</option>
                <option value="250">250g</option>
                <option value="500">500g</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td>I want to do calculation (selectedvalue / 1000) * Amount, that amount want to reflect here</td>
    </tr>
    <tr align="center">
        <td>2</td>
        <td>Product2</td>
        <td>200</td>
        <td>
            <select id="grams">
                <option value=""></option>
                <option value="100">100g</option>
                <option value="250">250g</option>
                <option value="500">500g</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td>I want to do calculation (selectvalue / 1000) * Amount, that amount want to reflect here</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: Please learn to format in SO... please [read the FAQ's](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).  Any code blocks should start with 4-spaces. I would do it for you, but there is simply too much, and I don't have the time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might help you understand how to format your table to get the values

```
$(function(){
  $('select').change(function(){
        var td_id = 'row'+$(this).attr('id');
        var val = $(this).val();
        var amount = $('.'+td_id+'-amount').html();
        $('#'+td_id).html(val/1000*amount);
  });
});
```

In the example you have to add some extra `ids` and `classes`. See [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Spokey/2ey8s/)

(I thought you wanted to have more than 2 rows. The other answers may be more easy to use in your case)

Comment: Thank you so much for your wonderful help.

Answer (score 1):

First, you can not have two elements with the same id.  ID's need to unique.  So you'll need to change the second select box's id.

I then placed an id on the td where the calculations will go and an id on the td's that contain the amounts.

```
<table border="1">
<tbody>
<tr>
    <td width="334">S.No.</td>
    <td width="334">Product Name</td>
    <td width="334">Amount</td>
    <td width="334">Grams/Kg</td>
    <td width="334">Final Amount</td>
</tr>
<tr align="center">
    <td>1</td>
    <td>Product1</td>
    <td id="amtFirst">100</td>
    <td>
        <select id="grams">
            <option value=""></option>
            <option value="100">100g</option>
            <option value="250">250g</option>
            <option value="500">500g</option>
        </select>
    </td>
    <td id="firstCalculation"></td>
</tr>
<tr align="center">
    <td>2</td>
    <td>Product2</td>
    <td id="amtSecond">200</td>
    <td>
        <select id="secondGrams">
            <option value=""></option>
            <option value="100">100g</option>
            <option value="250">250g</option>
            <option value="500">500g</option>
        </select>
    </td>
    <td id="secondCalculation"></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
```

Then you need to use jquery:

```
//handles the first select box
$('table').on('change','#grams',function(){
    var selection = $(this).val();
    var amount = $('#amtFirst').html();

    selection = (selection/1000)*amount;
    $('#firstCalculation').html(selection);
});

//handles the second select box
$('table').on('change','#secondGrams',function(){
    var selection = $(this).val();
    var amount = $('#amtSecond').html();

    selection = (selection/1000)*amount;
    $('#secondCalculation').html(selection);
});
```